# Error when two `programs.devnet` found in anchor

Tags: anchor

1. Could someone explain what the differences are to `[programs.localnet]`, `[programs.devnet]` and possibly `[programs.mainnet-beta]` defined in Anchor.toml

The [anchor-lang reference](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/manifest) for the manifest only mentions `programs.localnet`

> programs.localnet is used during testing on localnet where it's possible to load a program at genesis with the --bpf-program option on solana-test-validator

2. Why does having two `programs.localnet` or `programs.devnet` result in this error

```
Error: Unable to deserialize config: redefinition of table `programs.localnet` for key `programs.localnet` at line 8 column 1
```

I am trying to have multiple programs in my Anchor workspace.

Answer (score 3):

1. It just informs anchor what network you will be using to deploy your program. Whether its localnet, devnet, or the mainnet(`[programs.mainnet]`)
2. I believe you should be creating a seperate program directory for each program, and provide the idl for each program to use multiple programs in Anchor workspace.
   Something like

- `/programs/program1/src/lib.rs`
- `/programs/program2/src/lib.rs`

and

- `/programs/program1/target/idl/program1.json`
- `/programs/program2/target/idl/program2.json`

Then u should have to modify the anchor.toml file to read both the programs.

```
[programs.devnet]
lib1 = "<program1.keypair>"
idl1 = "<program1.idl>"
lib2 = "<program2.keypair>"
idl2 = "<program2.idl>"
```

Not entirely sure about whether anchor.toml config notations are correct... but I think this way u can use two programs

Comment: the `anchor new` CLI command takes care of the creation.

Comment: Thats fairly convenient then!

Comment: for the code snippet you shared, will I be using the paths to the idls?

Comment: I tried it via anchor now, and I dont think u will need to specify the path, Anchor will do it by itself. But u will have to build both the programs once, for anchor to generate the idl

Comment: Please mark as answered if ur query has been cleared